# Can't deserialize JSON into C# POCO

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, windows-8.1, poco

I can't convert JSON Object into C# class object I've tried many things but the same error pops up:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CoderwallDotNet.Api.Models.Account]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

I am using this JSON and tring to get the response in windows 8.1 application.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "time": 40,
    "srcLong": 35.909124,
    "srcLat": 31.973628,
    "destLong": 35.898258,
    "destLat": 31.985622,
    "subSites": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "location1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "location2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "locaion3"
        }
    ]
}]
```

and the I tried to read from the JSON using webclient but its not working it can't recognize it so I am using Newtonsoft.Json and I creted these class to get the response.

```
public class SubSite
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public double srcLong { get; set; }
    public double srcLat { get; set; }
    public double destLong { get; set; }
    public double destLat { get; set; }
    public List<SubSite> subSites { get; set; }
}

var serviceUri = "http://localhost:24728/api/sites";     

var client = new HttpClient();            

var response = await client.GetAsync(serviceUri);            

var datafile = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsyn();                        

List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(datafile); 

test1234.Text = data.ToString();//i am trying to for eample destlat
```

but I can't get the value I am getting the response and everything is fine but idk how to put it into object and use it where ever I want. For example, I want to get the value of time and the other but I have problem with List of subsites or get the location inside the subsites or `srclong` or `srclat` and here is the project how to get the Json to c# object:
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=e648f5a0f179f346&id=E648F5A0F179F346%218429&ithint=folder,rar&authkey=!ALKlJdwsb8ER2FA

Comment: Just as a side note: it's spelled JSON (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation), but it is pronounced like "Jason" :)

Comment: Given the error has:
`System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CoderwallDotNet.Api.Models.Account]` I think you are not showing the correct code, or the correct error.

Comment: I've edited to correct your terms a little; the C# class is the POCO. The JSON is just JSON, it can't be POCO because POCO stands for Plain Old CLR Object. JSON knows nothing of the CLR.

Comment: There lies the interest of serialization.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CoderwallDotNet.Api.Models.Account] sry that was from other post I found on net it was the same error run the code and u will see it why else I will share the project ?? because I really need help that's the true project

Answer (score 1):

[image]This works fine:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(datafile)
```

Comment: I know but the problem I cant access the data Idk how to access it the values how to get the value separately.

Comment: You can access the properties from the data object

Comment: but I don't know how to access the properties from data object. show me example that's my problem I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize into a `dynamic` object if you are not too particular about losing intellisense. One advantage to using a dynamic is that you don't have to create classes just to be able to deserialize and also that you don't need to update your class structures if the returned data has changed. As an example you can do this:

```
dynamic jsonValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
foreach (dynamic rootObject in jsonValue)
{
   theData.destLong.Value <-- use it anyway you want, store in a variable, etc.
   // to get to each of the subSite in the rootObject
   foreach (dynamic subSite in rootObject.subSites)
   {
       subSite.id.Value <-- returns an int based on your data
       subSite.name.Value <-- returns a string based on your data
   }
}
// where jsonData constains the json string you posted
```

The `foreaeach` is important because the data you posted will result into an array. You can also just do a `jsonValue[0]` but watch out for errors for null values, which you should be checking anyway starting with the returned json string.

Comment: ok thank u I will try it and give you the result. and I will not need the data folder rootobject and subsite clases ??

Comment: Based on your posted sample, there is no "data" at root. If there is and you have something like `{"data": [  ... ]}` then just do a `foreach(dynamic rootObject in jsonValue.data)` plus the rest of the code.